# TIKTOK LoginKit, redirect_uri bad

Tags: node.js, redirect, oauth-2.0, tiktok

- I just followed the documentation for use auth2  with tiktok.
- My URL Redirect is setting
  [image]
- And my code follow that

```
     @Get('/tiktok/redirect')
        loginTicTok(
            @Res() res,
        ) {
            const csrfState = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
            res.cookie('csrfState', csrfState, { maxAge: 60000 });
            let url =`${this.config.get('tictokURL')}`;
            url +=`?client_key=${this.config.get('tictokClientKey')}`;
            url +=`&scope=video.upload`;
            url += '&response_type=code';
            url += '&redirect_uri=https://reelcrm-backend.herokuapp.com/social-network/tiktok/';
            res.redirect(url);
        }
```

- My link generate is:
- But the problems is tiktok is getting show me bad request from URL:

> https://www.tiktok.com/v2/auth/authorize/?client_key=myclientcode&scope=video.upload&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://reelcrm-backend.herokuapp.com/social-network/tiktok/

[image]

Comment: Did you problem solved after follow @vikram_parmar's answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your TikTok request URL is right https://www.tiktok.com/v2/auth/authorize/?client_key=myclientcode&scope=video.upload&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://reelcrm-backend.herokuapp.com/social-network/tiktok/.

And I also your redirect uri is same but you need to **encode your URL** parameters [tiktok guideline for URL encode parameters.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6uC9.png)

so try using encoded URL query params this is reference https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/login-kit-web